# Using Multiple PHP Drop Downs To Filter MySQL Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

Heres a pic of my database table -> [MySQL-Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOAZr.png)

Im trying to create a search page with drop down selectors to filter through each of the last 8 columns.
I want the the drop down selectors to be able to select multiple entries (I have this working already)
I also want them to preload values from data already entered into my table columns. (I also got this working with the help of tutorials... although I admit I don't fully understand how this part works)

Using these tutorials i've created a php page that contains 8 drop down selectors that automatically pull values from their respective columns. Id like to be able to filter results from my table using either all (or some) of these column filters. 
For Example... Say I want to show all entries that fall under Genre=Metal, AND KeySig=E minor, AND Tempo=Fast... 
I might use a mysql command like 
mysql> SELECT id, NameUrl, Genre, KeySig, TimeSig, Tempo, Tuning, EntType, Recording, RecYear FROM test_table WHERE Genre = 'Metal' AND KeySig = 'E minor' AND Tempo = 'Fast';

Essentially i'm trying to do the same thing via a php webpage. 
With the code I have right now only my first drop down selector "Genre" actually filters through anything. The rest of the filters are just there.. they're not set up to do anything yet. I need help pulling $_POST requests from my remaining drop downs and coming up with code that will filter through my columns using multiple variables via the AND operator.

I hope this makes sense... Im not much of a computer guy.. more of a musician. Building this as a tool to help me out with my writing workflow.
Hope someone can help - Thanks

DBController.php

```
     <?php
 class DBController {
     private $host = "localhost";
     private $user = "root";
     private $password = "password";
     private $database = "test";
     private $conn;

         function __construct() {
         $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
          } 
     function connectDB() {
         $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
         return $conn;
     }
         function runQuery($query) {
                 $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $resultset[] = $row;
                 }      
                 if(!empty($resultset))
                 return $resultset;
     }
 }
 ?>
```

testsearch.php

```
        <?php
 include 'DBController.php';
 $db_handle = new DBController();
 $GenreResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Genre FROM test_table ORDER BY Genre ASC");
 $TempoResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Tempo FROM test_table ORDER BY Tempo ASC");
 $KeySigResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT KeySig FROM test_table ORDER BY KeySig ASC");
 $TimeSigResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT TimeSig FROM test_table ORDER BY TimeSig ASC");
 $TuningResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Tuning FROM test_table ORDER BY Tuning ASC");
 $EntTypeResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT EntType FROM test_table ORDER BY EntType ASC");
 $RecordingResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Recording FROM test_table ORDER BY Recording ASC");
 $RecYearResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT RecYear FROM test_table ORDER BY RecYear ASC");
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <title>Riff Bank - Search & Upload</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h2>Riff Bank - Search & Upload</h2>
     <form method="POST" name="Genre" action="testsearch.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="Genre[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Genre</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($GenreResult)) {
                             foreach ($GenreResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $GenreResult[$key]['Genre'] . '">' . $GenreResult[$key]['Genre'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="KeySig[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Key</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($KeySigResult)) {
                             foreach ($KeySigResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $KeySigResult[$key]['Tempo'] . '">' . $KeySigResult[$key]['KeySig'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="TimeSig[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select TIme Signature</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($TimeSigResult)) {
                             foreach ($TimeSigResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $TimeSigResult[$key]['TimeSig'] . '">' . $TimeSigResult[$key]['TimeSig'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <form method="POST" name="search" action="index.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="Tempo[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Tempo</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="index.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($TempoResult)) {
                             foreach ($TempoResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $TempoResult[$key]['Tempo'] . '">' . $TempoResult[$key]['Tempo'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="Tuning[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Tuning</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($TuningResult)) {
                             foreach ($TuningResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $TuningResult[$key]['Tuning'] . '">' . $TuningResult[$key]['Tuning'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="EntType[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Entry Type</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($EntTypeResult)) {
                             foreach ($EntTypeResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $EntTypeResult[$key]['EntType'] . '">' . $EntTypeResult[$key]['EntType'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="Recording[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Recording Type</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="testsearch.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($RecordingResult)) {
                             foreach ($RecordingResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $RecordingResult[$key]['Recording'] . '">' . $RecordingResult[$key]['Recording'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <form method="POST" name="search" action="index.php">
         <div id="demo-grid">
             <div class="search-box">
                 <select id="Place" name="RecYear[]" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Year</option>
                     <form method="POST" name="search" action="index.php">
                         <?php
                         if (! empty($RecYearResult)) {
                             foreach ($RecYearResult as $key => $value) {
                                 echo '<option value="' . $RecYearResult[$key]['RecYear'] . '">' . $RecYearResult[$key]['RecYear'] . '</option>';
                             }
                         }
                         ?>
                 </select><br> <br>
                 <button id="Filter">Search</button>
             </div>
             <?php
                 if (! empty($_POST['Genre'])) {
                     ?>
                     <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">

                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th><strong>id</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Genre</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Key</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Time Sig</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Tempo</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Tuning</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Type</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Recording</strong></th>
                         <th><strong>Year</strong></th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 <?php
                     $query = "SELECT * from test_table";
                     $i = 0;
                     $selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['Genre']);
                     $selectedOption = "";
                     while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
                         $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['Genre'][$i] . "'";
                         if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
                             $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
                         }

                         $i ++;
                     }
                     $query = $query . " WHERE Genre in (" . $selectedOption . ")";

                     $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
                 }
                 if (! empty($result)) {
                     foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                         ?>
                 <tr>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_1"><?php echo $result[$key]['id']; ?></div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_2"><?php echo $result[$key]['NameUrl']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_3"><?php echo $result[$key]['Genre']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_4"><?php echo $result[$key]['KeySig']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_5"><?php echo $result[$key]['TimeSig']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_6"><?php echo $result[$key]['Tempo']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_7"><?php echo $result[$key]['Tuning']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_8"><?php echo $result[$key]['EntType']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_9"><?php echo $result[$key]['Recording']; ?> </div></td>
                         <td><div class="col" id="user_data_10"><?php echo $result[$key]['RecYear']; ?> </div></td>
                     </tr>
                 <?php
                     }
                     ?>

                 </tbody>
             </table>
             <?php
                 }
                 ?>  
         </div>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
             </div>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

ADAM UPDATE: DBController.php ... Like This??

```
     <?php
 class DBController {
     public $host = "localhost";
     public $user = "root";
     public $password = "password";
     public $database = "test";
     public $conn;

         function __construct() {
         $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
     }  
     function connectDB() {
         $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this- 
>password,$this->database);
         return $conn;
         $stmt = $db_handle->conn->prepare($query);
     }
         function runQuery($query) {
                 $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $resultset[] = $row;
                 }      
                 if(!empty($resultset))
                 return $resultset;
     }
 }
 ?>
```

[testsearch.php Browser Search - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCD7X.png)

[testsearch.php Browser Results - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Xlp.png)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would get filters in one multidimensional array

```
    include 'DBController.php';
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $filters = [];

    $filters['Genre'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Genre FROM test_table ORDER BY Genre ASC"), 'Genre');
    $filters['Tempo'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Tempo FROM test_table ORDER BY Tempo ASC"), 'Tempo');
    $filters['KeySig'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT KeySig FROM test_table ORDER BY KeySig ASC"), 'KeySig');
    $filters['TimeSig'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT TimeSig FROM test_table ORDER BY TimeSig ASC"), 'TimeSig');
    $filters['Tuning'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Tuning FROM test_table ORDER BY Tuning ASC"), 'Tuning');
    $filters['EntType'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT EntType FROM test_table ORDER BY EntType ASC"), 'EntType');
    $filters['Recording'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Recording FROM test_table ORDER BY Recording ASC"), 'Recording');
    $filters['RecYear'] = array_column($db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT RecYear FROM test_table ORDER BY RecYear ASC"),'RecYear');
```

in < html > you should have only one < form > and all < select > in it & the < button > with type="submit" attribute .
Close your < div >s properly. You should use id's value in any tag only once like (id="Place").
You don't need an empty option tag in multiple select unless the value of it is used.
Prepare your query statement with the values sent to server from client to prevent sql injections!!!

Example:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>Riff Bank - Search & Upload</title>
        <style>
            .search-box select {
                min-width: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Riff Bank - Search & Upload</h2>
        <form method="POST" name="Genre">
            <div id="demo-grid">
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Genre<br>
                    <select id="Genre" name="Genre[]" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['Genre'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['Genre'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Key<br>
                    <select id="KeySig" name="KeySig[]" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['KeySig'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['KeySig'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Time Signature<br>
                    <select id="TimeSig" name="TimeSig[]" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['TimeSig'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['TimeSig'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Tempo<br>
                    <select id="Tempo" name="Tempo[]" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['Tempo'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['Tempo'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Tuning<br>
                    <select id="Tuning" name="Tuning[]" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['Tuning'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['Tuning'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Entry Type<br>
                    <select id="EntType" name="EntType[]" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['EntType'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['EntType'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Recording Type<br>
                    <select id="Recording" name="Recording[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['Recording'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['Recording'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    Select Year<br>
                    <select id="RecYear" name="RecYear[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <?php
                            if (!empty($filters['RecYear'])) {
                                foreach ($filters['RecYear'] as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <button id="Filter" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        if (!empty($_POST) && count($_POST)) {
            //filter the array $_POST with the keys representing your filters & fields in your DB that you trust
            $request_filters = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(['Genre','Tempo','KeySig','TimeSig','Tuning','EntType','Recording']));
            if(count($request_filters)) {
                ?>
                <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <strong>id</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Name</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Genre</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Key</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Time Sig</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Tempo</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Tuning</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Type</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Recording</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Year</strong>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                //then build up your prepare query statement
                $params = [];
                $query = "SELECT * from test_table WHERE ";
                $extra_query = [];
                foreach ($request_filters as $field => $values) {
                    $extra_query[] = "{$field} IN (?" . str_repeat(', ?', count($values) - 1) . ")";
                    $params = array_merge($params, $values);
                }
                $query .= implode(' AND ',$extra_query);
                $stmt = $db_handle->conn->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s',count($params)), ...$params);
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $stmt_result = $stmt->get_result();
                    if($stmt_result && $stmt_result->num_rows){
                        ?>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while($row = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()){
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['NameUrl']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['Genre']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['KeySig']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['TimeSig']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['Tempo']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['Tuning']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['EntType']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['Recording']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col"><?php echo $row['RecYear']; ?></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="10">No results!</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
                </table>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Controller:

```
    <?php
    class DBController {
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user = "root";
        private $password = "password";
        private $database = "test";
        public $conn;
        function __construct() {
            $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
        }
        function connectDB() {
            $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
             return $conn;
            }
        function runQuery($query) {
            $result = $this->conn->query($query);
            $resultset = [];
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
            }
            return $resultset;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Btw in your DBController.php you need to make public your $conn;
and use it for prepare like so : $stmt = $db_handle->conn->prepare($query);

Comment: Hey Adam! Thanks a lot man! Im having a couple issues with this code that im hoping you can help with.

1) The table columns dont automatically appear in my drop down selectors anymore. Instead the word "Array" appears for each column.. (ex. if theres 5 different entries within one column, it will pull up 5 options all saying "Array"..) and it continues to do this for all other selection menus... it appears to be recognizing how many entries are in each column though.

Comment: 2. When I select something and hit search no results are returned and instead i'm hit with errors
a. "Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in /Users/jamiebekyarovich/Sites/testsearch2.php on line 196"Fatal error: 
b. "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null in /Users/jamiebekyarovich/Sites/testsearch2.php on line 196"
c.  "Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null in /Users/jamiebekyarovich/Sites/testsearch2.php on line 196"

Comment: Code at 196 =
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s',count($params)), ...$params);

Ive Included
$stmt = $db_handle->conn->prepare($query);
in my DBController.php but i'm not sure if i put it in the right spot.

updated DBController.php included in edited post

Comment: I updated my answer try the code now. i added array_column on getting the filters , DBController public $conn and the use of it, for the prepare statement.